# how to compare the strings of two richtext fields

Tags: lotusscript

I want a lotusscript code which can compare the strings of two richtext fields. I have two forms named form1 and form2 and in each form i have one richtext field name "body" and "body1" through my code i can get the value of both the fields now i want to compare these two fields and show the difference of string in a message box.

My code is :

```
Sub Click(Source As Button)

 Dim session As NotesSession
 Dim db As NotesDatabase
 Dim dc As NotesDocumentCollection
 Dim doc, doc1 As NotesDocument
 Dim text1 As NotesItem
 Dim text2 As NotesItem
 Dim str1 As String

 Set session = New NotesSession
 Set db = session.CurrentDatabase
 Set dc = db.UnprocessedDocuments
 Set doc = dc.GetFirstDocument
 Set doc1=dc.GetNextDocument(doc)

 Set text1=doc.getfirstitem("body")
 Set text2 = doc1.getfirstitem( "body1" )

 'Forall v In text1.Values

 v=text1.Values
 v1=text2.Values
 Messagebox( v ) 
 Messagebox( v1) 
 If Len(v) =Len(v1) Then 
  Msgbox"both the fields have same number of strings"
 Else
  If Len(v) >Len(v1) Then 
   Msgbox"the length of the string in body field of form1 is greater"
  Else
   Msgbox"the length of the string in body1 field of form2 is greater"
  End If
 End If


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement a simple text diff algorithm. If you don't want to reinvent the wheel, I suggest grabbing a VB diff funcion, and adapting it to Lotusscript.